# Highlight multiple keyword with color in the given string

Tags: php, regex, syntax-highlighting, str-replace

I want to highlight multiple text with background color in the given string.

I am using this code:

```
<style>
.highlight{
background: #CEDAEB;
}
</style>
<?
$str = 'Led Plant Lamp , nikeshoes,  hid xenon lamps, torchs, xenon lamp, mp3, mp4, sola, glass';
$keywords = array("k span","htc","nike","tma","ass","ck","rei","bov");
$style = 'highlight';
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
{
    $replacement = "<span class='".$style."'>".$keyword."</span>";
    $str = str_ireplace($keyword, $replacement, $str);
}
return $str;
?>

Output:Led Plant Lamp , ass='highlight'>nikeshoes,  hid xenon lamps, torchs, xenon lamp, mp3, mp4, sola, glass
```

str_ireplace function replace keyword ass with span class. Kindly help me where i m wrong in this code

Comment: The mistake is in the fact that you replace ass after some replacements have already been made. Move ass to the first position of your keywords and it should work

Comment: this is temporary solution because $keywords array is dynamic if $keyword having span element then span tag replace with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.highlight{
background: #CEDAEB;
}
</style>
<?
$str = 'Led Plant Lamp , nikeshoes,  hid xenon lamps, torchs, xenon lamp, mp3, mp4, sola, glass';
$keywords = array("k span","htc","nike","tma","ass","ck","rei","bov");
$style = 'highlight';
$arr1 = array();
$input = $str;
$str = explode(" ",$str);
foreach($str as $index=>$strings)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($keywords); $i++)
    {
        if (stristr($strings, $keywords[$i]) !== false){                
            if(!isset($arr1[$index]))
            {
                $str_first_position = stripos($strings,$keywords[$i]);
                $str_last_position = strlen($keywords[$i])-1 + $str_first_position;
                $str_first_char = substr($strings,0,$str_first_position);
                $str_last_char = substr($strings,$str_last_position+1,strlen($strings));
                $arr1[$index] = $str_first_char."<span class='".$style."'>".$keywords[$i]."</span>".$str_last_char;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
$arr2 = $arr1+$str;
ksort($arr2);
return implode(" ",$arr2);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<style>
.highlight{
    background: #CEDAEB;
}
</style>
<?php
$str = "Led Plant Lamp , nikeshoes,  hid xenon lamps, torchs, xenon lamp, mp3, mp4, sola, glass";
$keywords = array("ass", "k span", "htc", "nike","tma","ck","rei","bov");
$style = 'highlight';
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
{
    $replacement = "<span class='highlight'>".$keyword."</span>";
    $str = str_ireplace($keyword, $replacement, $str);
}
var_dump($str);
?>
```

Comment: this is temporary solution because $keywords array is dynamic if $keyword having span element then span tag replace with this